# update table with random values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I have two tables, lets say Table1(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) and Table2(Col1).

I want to update some cols in Table1.

For each row in Table1 where Col1 ends with '001' (assume all values are at least length 4) I want to:

1.place a random number from the set (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90) in Col2.

2.place a random 9 digit number in Col3.

3.place a random value from Table2 Col1 in Table1 Col4.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
 RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),   
 Col1 int,
 Col2 int,
 Col3 int,
 Col4 int.
)

DECLARE @RowCount int,
@numberRecords int

select @NumberRecords = count(*) from mytable
SET @RowCount = 1

WHILE @RowCount <= @NumberRecords
BEGIN

UPDATE MyTable
 SET  Col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 RandomColumn1 
         FROM   SampleData 
         ORDER BY NEWID()) 

 WHERE RowID = @RowCount


 SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1
END
```

Hope that is some help.. an expansion of my answer.. as you can see I create your table but add a row-id column that increments.. i then create a loop that runs the update statment on a row per row basis.

Very similar to how a cursor would function but hopefully quicker.

Comment: I actually developed a set based solution just before you posted this. Thanks so much for your help! +1

Answer (score 1):

I think this can get you started on the right road.

Build a table of sample data with incrementing numbers that suit your needs. You can use a loop, but a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) or [a recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) will be much faster if you're doing many rows. Then, update the appropriate columns of `Table1` with sample data `ORDER BY NEWID()`. This will randomize the order of the select-set.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET  Col1 = (SELECT TOP 1 RandomColumn1
             FROM   SampleData
             ORDER BY NEWID())
```

You may also see if **[RedGate's Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqldatagenerator&gclid=CJKm9_K_4aQCFc5L5QodtygUdw)** will work for you. I have it, but have never used it.

Comment: can't use an order by clause in a subquery unless you use top1 and that would result in placing the SAME random value in each record.

Comment: @kralco, adding `TOP 1` will **not** put the same value in each field since `ORDER BY NEWID()` is specified. However, I am modifying based on your other observation (can't have an `ORDER BY` in a subquery without a `TOP`)

Comment: @kralco, I see; it must be because the `TOP 1` query is only being executed once. When I tested just that statement, I received different results each execution.

Comment: @kralco, while working on a solution, I've run into a lot of limitations that necessitate creating a lot of dependencies (`TALLY TABLE`, `VIEW`for getting a `NEWID()`, a `FUNCTION` to generate random numbers). I'd look elsewhere; sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: The Top 1 query will only run once and update the column based on the value it returns. Off the top of my head you could create a RowID column (incrementing number) get the min / max values of your column where your updating and use a while 1:1 loops incrementing a counter variable each time until you reach the same value as your max row-id.

Comment: @Brad - Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to always use a set based solution. This is the set based solution I developed. I tested it and it works.

```
Update Table1
   Set Col2 = (Cast(CAST(newid() AS binary(1)) AS int) % 9 + 1) *10
 Where Substring(Table1.Col1,len(Table1.Col1)-2,3) = '001'

Update Table1
   Set Col3 = Cast(CAST(newid() AS binary(3)) AS int)
 Where Substring(Table1.Col1,len(Table1.Col1)-2,3) = '001'

Create table #temp1(tCol1 varchar(50), 
             tCol2 varchar(10),randomnum varchar(max) )

      Insert Into #temp1
      Select Table1.Col1,Table2.Col1,newid() as random1
        From Table1 
  Cross Join Table2 
       Where Substring(Table1.Col1,len(Table1.Col1)-2,3) = '001'

      Update Table1
         Set Table1.Col4 = tCol2
        From (
              Select tCol1,tCol2,a.randomnum 
                From (
                           Select Max(randomnum) As randomnum 
                             From #temp1 Group By tCol1
                     ) a 
           Left Join #temp1 On a.randomnum = #temp1.randomnum
             ) b  
          Inner Join Table1 On b.tCol1 = Table1.Col1

          Drop table #temp1
```

Comment: "This is the set based solution": you are using three updates plus a staging table. Erm, isn't that a *procedural* approach?

Comment: Well as i'm only updating 350 rows i didn't feel it necessary to combine into one step. But I certainly can if it would be helpful to someone... Also. The staging table is unavoidable, barring the use of With table.... Either way a temp table or a table variable or whatever it's called is logically the same thing. It's necessary to reference the same instance of a nondeterministic query more than once. You must save it somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer to run the below code and wait for sometime to run and update random values

```
while 1=1
BEGIN
    UPDATE top (10) a
     SET  value =rand() * 100
    from (select top 10 * from 
            MyTable
     order by newid()
     ) a
END
```

Answer (score -1):

I tend to use something like this:

```
WITH SampleData (entity_number, entity_name)
     AS (
         ... row constructors here...
        ),
     SampleDataOrdered (order_col, entity_number, entity_name)
     AS (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()), 
                S1.entity_number, S1.entity_name
           FROM SampleData AS S1
        )
MERGE INTO MyBaseTable...;
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you mean. Could you be more specific please? How to update table1 col4 with a random value from table2 col1? Thanks!